# How can I compare old file with the new file in cloud storage and then getting the logging information through Cloud Function for the same?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

So, I wanted to create triggers in Cloud Function. Using google.storage.object.finalize trigger event while deploying the Cloud Function. Now the challenge I'm facing is how can I get to know the changes which have come to the file by overriding it and which are present in Cloud Storage.

Comment: The function won't tell you what changed.  The only way for you to know is to fetch the old version and find some way to compare it to the new version.  This is entirely up to you to design and implement.

Comment: @DougStevenson is right. You may follow this guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank You but can you give me a little more insight how can I achieve this?

Comment: @RishabhPagaria Have you tried the answer below?

Comment: @JMGelilio Hi, I'm still trying this and also trying to understand the code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ***@Doug Stevenson***, you need to get the old version of the file and compare it to the new version, in order to achieve it, you need to enable the [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) in Cloud Storage.

I managed to create a simple Cloud functions trigger and the code returns a true or false response if there are changes between old and new versions of the file. Please note that the below code only compares **text files**.

`Python`

```
from google.cloud import storage
def hello_gcs(event, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    file = event
    BUCKET_NAME = file['bucket']
    print(f"Processing file: {file['name']}.")

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(BUCKET_NAME, versions=True)

    generation = []
    blob_name = []

    #list objects including the non current version
    for blob in blobs:
        #add the generation and object name in the list
        generation.append(blob.generation)
        blob_name.append(blob.name)

    #get the last two item in the generation list
    sliced_generation = generation[-2:]

    #print the old version txt file as string
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

    old_blob = bucket.blob(str(blob_name[0]), generation=sliced_generation[0])
    old_version = old_blob.download_as_text()

    #print the new version txt file as string
    new_blob = bucket.blob(str(blob_name[0]), generation=sliced_generation[1])
    new_version = new_blob.download_as_text()

    #compare the two strings (result: True or False)
    return old_version == new_version
```

You may check this code/logic and improve to achieve your goal.